# How to dynamically end an include_tasks loop in Ansible

Tags: ansible

Due to the fact that we cannot run loop on block with Ansible, therefore I have to do `include_tasks` in the loop where the referenced file contains more than 1 task.

What if I need to dynamically end the loop earlier (lets say 5 iterations instead of 10 as defined by the `loop:` statements). trying to use `when:` condition but that only take in pre-defined/statically defined variables, if I have to update the variable that will be evaluated in `when:` for each iteration, I have to do `register:` or `set_fact` in a task before that, which is not possible when the loop task is running...

Also in the `included_tasks` I can set `meta: end_play` to end the loop and the play execution but that is not what I want, the play should continue after the loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to break loop in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47263471/how-to-break-loop-in-ansible)

Comment: Not really, I have updated the question title to distinguish from the other question, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't end it. You can only skip the rest. For example,

```yaml
    - command: "echo {{ item }}"
      with_sequence: end=5
      register: out
      when: out.stdout|d(0)|int < 3
```

gives (on localhost)

```yaml
  changed: [localhost] => (item=1)
  changed: [localhost] => (item=2)
  changed: [localhost] => (item=3)
  skipping: [localhost] => (item=4) 
  skipping: [localhost] => (item=5)
```

See:

- [Add "break_when" to the "loop_control" #51881](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/51881)
- [Ansible loop interface redesign #140](https://github.com/ansible/proposals/issues/140)

---

**include_tasks**

The *include_tasks* situation is quite complex. The attribute [*ignore_conditional*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_tasks_module.html#attribute-ignore_conditional) says:

> The action is not subject to conditional execution so it will ignore the when: keyword

You can't use *when* with *include_tasks*, but you can [*apply*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_tasks_module.html#parameter-apply) keywords, including the keyword *when*, to the tasks within the include. For example, create the file

```yaml
shell> cat tasks_1.yml
- name: Display item
  debug:
    var: item
- name: Execute command
  command: "echo {{ item }}"
  register: out
- name: Display stdout
  debug:
    var: out.stdout
```

When you include this file

```yaml
    - include_tasks:
        file: tasks_1.yml
        apply:
          when: out.stdout|d(0)|int < 3
      with_sequence: end=5
```

you apply the condition *"to the tasks within the include"*. Effectively, this will make the included tasks look like below

```yaml
- name: Display item
  debug:
    var: item
  when: out.stdout|d(0)|int < 3
- name: Execute command
  command: "echo {{ item }}"
  register: out
  when: out.stdout|d(0)|int < 3
- name: Display stdout
  debug:
    var: out.stdout
  when: out.stdout|d(0)|int < 3
```

Run the play below

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - include_tasks:
        file: tasks_1.yml
        apply:
          when: out.stdout|d(0)|int < 3
      with_sequence: end=5
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [include_tasks] **************************************************************************
included: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-389/tasks_1.yml for localhost => (item=1)
included: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-389/tasks_1.yml for localhost => (item=2)
included: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-389/tasks_1.yml for localhost => (item=3)
included: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-389/tasks_1.yml for localhost => (item=4)
included: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-389/tasks_1.yml for localhost => (item=5)

TASK [Display item] ***************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  item: '1'

TASK [Execute command] ************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Display stdout] *************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  out.stdout: '1'

TASK [Display item] ***************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  item: '2'

TASK [Execute command] ************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Display stdout] *************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  out.stdout: '2'

TASK [Display item] ***************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  item: '3'

TASK [Execute command] ************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Display stdout] *************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Display item] ***************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Execute command] ************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Display stdout] *************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  out.stdout: VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!

TASK [Display item] ***************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  item: '5'

TASK [Execute command] ************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Display stdout] *************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]
```

You can see that all iterations are included at once and then executed serially. The results look fine until `item: '4'`. The explanation always depends on the current value of the variable *out.stdout* before the execution of a task:

- [ok] [Display item] item: '3'; out.stdout=2
- [changed] [Execute command] out.stdout=2
- [skipping] [Display stdout] out.stdout=3
- [skipping] [Display item] out.stdout=3
- [skipping] [Execute command] out.stdout=3
- [ok] [Display stdout] out.stdout VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!
  (*default(0)* will apply because there is no attribute *stdout* in the registered
  variable *out* from the previous task)
- [ok] [Display item] item: '5'; default(0)
- [changed] [Execute command] default(0)
- [skipping] [Display stdout] out.stdout=5

This is unusable.

---

You can improve the framework by creating a variable *condition*. For example, put the tasks into a block and always set the condition

```yaml
shell> cat tasks_2.yml
- block:

    - name: Execute command {{ item }}
      command: "echo {{ item }}"
      register: out
    - debug:
        var: out.stdout

  always:

    - set_fact:
        condition: "{{ out.stdout|int < 3 }}"
```

Run the play below

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - include_tasks:
        file: tasks_2.yml
        apply:
          when: condition|d(true)
      with_sequence: end=5
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
TASK [include_tasks] **************************************************************************
included: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-389/tasks_2.yml for localhost => (item=1)
included: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-389/tasks_2.yml for localhost => (item=2)
included: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-389/tasks_2.yml for localhost => (item=3)
included: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-389/tasks_2.yml for localhost => (item=4)
included: /export/scratch/tmp7/test-389/tasks_2.yml for localhost => (item=5)

TASK [Execute command 1] **********************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  out.stdout: '1'

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Execute command 2] **********************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  out.stdout: '2'

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Execute command 3] **********************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  out.stdout: '3'

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Execute command 4] **********************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Execute command 5] **********************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] *******************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]
```

This seems reasonable.

Comment: Thanks, skipping is good enough for me, but it seems I cannot even do that with `include_tasks` instead of a `command:` execution since `include_tasks` does not return value (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701062/how-can-ansible-register-in-a-variable-the-result-of-including-a-playbook)  thus the `register: out` cannot be dynamically evaluated after each iteration.

Comment: You can [apply](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_tasks_module.html#parameter-apply) a condition. I added examples.